# Azure Devops Server 2019 - Only build if changes, otherwise use old artifacts

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Sorry if the title seems a bit trivial but I am trying to understand how to set up my build definition in a way where the code is not being built continuously.

I have a build definition that kicks off every hour. It runs an automated test. The source code for this is rarely updated, so is there a way to have it only build a new version if there has been changes?

I hope I am wording this right, but a developer had warned me earlier that what I am doing currently by building every hour is unnecessary as we only want to build when there are changes to the source code.

Is there a way to configure a build definition to not always build and create new build artifacts, but rather just to use latest artifacts and move on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a build definition that kicks off every hour. It runs an automated test. The source code for this is rarely updated, so is there a way to have it only build a new version if there has been changes?

There is a checkbox for this right under the scheduler.
[image]

> Is there a way to configure a build definition to not always build and create new build artifacts, but rather just to use latest artifacts and move on?

Not in a build, but you could move the testing into a release-pipeline that per default only uses the latest artifact.

If your automated tests are purely unittests and no integrationtests then you should consider using CI-Trigger instead. Hourly tests only make sense if your tests are more integrationtests than unittests

Comment: Well they are more like alert tests.. it is not the best approach but right now its all we have set up and has been working great so far. They are selenium tests that run every hour and do some important alerting tasks. I saw this checkbox, but we cant use this because then they would never run. What is the CI-Trigger?

Comment: @Tree55Topz CI-Trigger means "Continous Integration". The build will kick off when code is pushed

Comment: Ok even still this will not work for us.. Seems like we may want to pursue a way to run this with like a windows task scheduler or something like that. Thanks